How to disable window dragging from the top bar in GNOME?
I’m building an app that includes a feature allowing users to paint on the screen (specifically for touchscreens). I've noticed that when a window is maximized and the user clicks and drags down from the top bar, the window gets resized and starts moving with the cursor.
This behavior becomes problematic when users try to draw on top of the window, as it interrupts their painting. I’d like to disable this dragging functionality.
I’ve searched through the GNOME settings and attempted to use gsettings, but I haven’t found a way to specifically disable this feature. Is there a method to prevent maximized windows from being draggable via the top bar? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

For what it is worth, this is the only post I found about the same issue I was having with my maximized window experience. I couldn't find a setting anywhere to alter this behavior so I ended up creating a gnome extension to fix this so I figured I would share.
Once you have the extension skeleton setup, the magic bits to make this work (or not work) are:
Place this at the top to import the needed resource.
const Clutter = import.gi;
const Panel = imports.ui.panel;

Then you want to overwrite the function that is responsible for this:
Panel.Panel.prototype._tryDragWindow = function(event) {
    return Clutter.EVENT_PROPOGATE;
}

Hope this serves you well.
